# How can I reverse-sort a list in Red?

Tags: sorting, reverse, red

I've been playing with [Red](http://www.red-lang.org/), and I figured out how to sort a list:

```
--== Red 0.5.1 ==-- 
Type HELP for starting information. 

red>> list: [1 9 6 8]
== [1 9 6 8]
red>> sort list
== [1 6 8 9]
```

I'd like to sort this list backwards. How can I do this? I've tried various combinations:

```
red>> sort !list 
*** Script error: !list has no value
*** Where: sort
red>> !sort list
*** Script error: !sort has no value
*** Where: try
red>> sort reverse list
== [1 6 8 9]
red>> sort list reverse
*** Script error: reverse is missing its series argument
*** Where: reverse
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SORT has a /reverse refinement, which enables you to achieve what you want:

```
red>> sort/reverse [1 9 6 8]
== [9 8 6 1]
```

Also be aware that SORT *modifies* its argument.

You can find out more about how SORT (or any other function) works, by using the integrated help system:

```
red>> help sort

USAGE:
    sort series  /case  /skip  size  /compare  comparator  /part  length  /all  /reverse  /stable

DESCRIPTION:
     Sorts a series (modified); default sort order is ascending. 
     sort is of type: action!

ARGUMENTS:
     series  [series!]

REFINEMENTS:
     /case => Perform a case-sensitive sort.
     /skip => Treat the series as fixed size records.
         size  [integer!]
     /compare => Comparator offset, block or function.
         comparator  [integer! block! any-function!]
     /part => Sort only part of a series.
         length  [number! series!]
     /all => Compare all fields.
     /reverse => Reverse sort order.
     /stable => Stable sorting.
```

Comment: ...and for educational purposes, perhaps worth pointing out the ability to have done it with a custom compare function that reversed the bias of the comparison:  `sort/compare [1 6 9 8] function [a b] [a > b]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
red>> reverse sort list
== [9 8 6 1]
```

It is stack based, so you need to read it from right to left. You can write it as:

```
red>> reverse (sort list)
```

to imagine it better.

Comment: Noting, of course, that `sort/reverse list` will be more efficient than `reverse sort list` (because the process of the sort itself will be in reverse as a single operation...)

Comment: Of course, you are right. I have not checked if /reverse is already implemented in Red :)